# Find Replace variable data with common tag data

Tags: regex, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
I'm using NotePad++ and need help doing a find replace operation with variable data. Below is example of data:

Figure: 7k_50.111a.jpg

Figure: 7k_50.112a.jpg

Figure: 7k_50.113a.jpg

I need to replace the data above with the XML tag data below:

```
 (<internalRef internalRefId="7k_50.111a.jpg"internalRefTargetType="figure"></internalRef>)
```

The challenge is finding a way for the RegEx to REUSE the "7k_50.111a.jpg" data and insert within the quotes following the -

```
 internalRefId="
```

so that it automatically assigns itself its own RefID value that originates from the source data itself.  Is this possible?

If it's not possible,  how can I perform a find replace operation so that the source data above gets replaced with one common XML tag as shown below:

```
(<internalRef internalRefId="To Be Determined" internalRefTargetType="figure"></internalRef>)
```

It requires a RegEx to overwrite data that variates with new figure figure numbers. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

find: `Figure: (\S+)`

replace: `(<internalRef internalRefId="$1"internalRefTargetType="figure"></internalRef>)`

The parenthesis in the pattern are used to capture the content (`\S` -> all that is not a space), then you can refer to it in the replacement pattern with `$1`.

`Figure:` that is not captured is removed

Comment: Casmir, thank you very much for your reply.  The RegEx you posted is a MASTERPIECE!  It works flawlessly.  I thought it was going to be impossible to reuse source data and you figured out a way. Thanks again for the helpl

Comment: @Matrix: happy for you.